# Load Image to a button by Code behind(C#) in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Being a beg. me facing a problem. Please help me out.

I have created a "Style" in xaml and named it "CustomButton" for creating a button( which consist of Two Images and one Textblock) and want to load one of the image and text to TextBlock only at runtime i.e by code behind so that ill be having diffrent image and differnt text for each button. Actully, me need create an array of Buttons of the same style but diff. Image.

Answer (score 1):

```
Style mystyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["CustomButton"];
                Setter templateSetter = (Setter)mystyle.Setters[0];
                btnNext.Style = mystyle;
```

i created "style" in App.xaml and in code behind i call name style.

hope this help !

Thongaduka !

Answer (score 0):

Depending how much XAML you want, you need to either create a custom UserControl that inherits from Button, with a DependencyProperty for the background.

Or you can specify a ImageBrush for the Background property, and use that, along with the Content property, in your custom style. The ImageBrush approach is going to require some 3-4 lines of XAML per button.

And I wouldn't recommend creating any UI controls from C#, as you can do everything you want to using databindings. If you're attempting to render custom buttons inside a listbox, with a custom background, simple databinding work should do just fine, rather than creating any custom controls or styles.

Feel free to clarify (with code!) what you're attempting to do now.

Comment: Actually number of buttons i know only at runtime. And after that creating an array of buttons. Now, for each button me need to set an already defined "Style". This "Style" consist of 2 Images and 1 TextBlock but i need diff. Image and diff. text to same Style. Also,im giving code for "Style"

Comment: Why not simply bind that to a ListBox then, and have a ItemTemplate? That's the normal approach. Use a ObservableCollection, and you don't have to worry about how many items there is at design-time.

Comment: Might be very much possible and what you suggesting is wright thing to do, but me being new to C# and Silverlight not getting the correct punch OR you can say not getting the actual concept of binding. Could u pls get me some link or paste some example to me.

Comment: Do you understand databinding and observable collections? otherwise that's some good keywords to read up on for now.

Comment: yes, I do understand Collections(lists, vector etc..) and databinding is Binding a dep. prop.  of one element to some other element, I hope me right.but could not visulalize what has been hapenning behind the scenes

Comment: And Obse. Collcetion is having INotifyPropertyChange event to Collections